# 2-Norm of a complex matrix equation

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

I am having trouble understanding the following excerpt from a math text I'm working through:

[image]

My question specifically is how line 2 came about in the expansion. How do the real and imaginary parts expand like that? Also I can't figure out from the context what the cursive "I" means.

For reference, I understand how to expand the 2-norm squared of $||x + iy||^2 = x^2 + y^2$, but I can't seem to understand how it's working in this example.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "cursive 'I'"? I mean, what are you talking about?

Comment: I don't really know myself, I was hoping it would be obvious to someone from context =/

Comment: You misunderstood me. I don't know what you're talking about. Do you perhaps mean $\Im$?

Comment: Anyway, $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part. If you don't know this,then I'm really confused because you were able to note that the real and imaginary parts came into play here ("How do the real and imaginary parts expand like that?"). And if you know this, then I ask again: what are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\RR{\mathfrak{R}}\def\II{\mathfrak{I}}\def\ii{\iota}$
You might notice that $(\alpha+\ii\beta)(\gamma+\ii\delta)=\alpha\gamma-\beta\delta+\ii(\beta\gamma+\alpha\delta)$, where $\alpha,\ldots,\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\ii$ is the imaginary unit. Similar stuff holds, e.g., for matrix-vector products. So:
$$
\begin{align}
\|Ax-b\|_2^2
&=
\|(\RR A + \ii\II A)(\RR x + \ii\II x)-(\RR b + \ii\II b)\|_2^2 \\
&=
\|\RR A \RR x - \II A \II x -\RR b + \ii( \RR A \II x + \II A \RR x - \II b )\|_2^2 
\\
&=
\|\RR A \RR x - \II A \II x -\RR b\|_2^2 + \|\RR A \II x + \II A \RR x - \II b \|_2^2.
\end{align}
$$